# Get rows that don't contain any letters but given in regex Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

First of all, apologies if this is a duplicate question. I've done my best to search but was unsuccessful, and I couldn't even properly word my question in terms of keywords!

I need to write a Postgres query that will find all the rows that **do not** contain any letters but given in regex. I already found out that I'll need to use LIKE statement with regex. But I have no idea how to white proper conditions.

Example: letters are 'A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E'.

**The query should return**

1. APP
2. PAL
3. LAP
4. APPLE

**The query should not return**

1. PEL**T**
2. P**I**E
3. etc...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~` operator for regular expression in postgresql instead of LIKE and your regex should look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col ~ '^[APLE]+$';
```

wich mean match one or more character from the group `[APLE]`

So it can return :

```
APP 
PAL 
LAP 
APPLE
```

and not :

```
PELT
PIE
```

Comment: Yeh, that works now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6146f/4/0 i have added the * in my sql fiddle to allow for difference cases.

Comment: @Matt I already test it and it work try with `col ~ '^[APLE]+$'` instead i forgot ^ and $ anchors sorry